# Safest way to alloc stuff inside your viewdidload

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Declaration.

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) footballResultsParser * FBRP;
```

Method of alloc.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
 {
    if (FBRP == nil)
    {
     FBRP = [[footballResultsParser alloc] init];
     [FBRP updateResults];
    }
  }
```

Is that the proper and safe way you alloc objects in your viewDidLoad?
I assume its possible that viewDidLoad will get called more than once and the object might already exists.

To dealloc safely.

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    if (FBRP != nil)
    {
     [FBRP release];
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do memory management that this?

Comment: your retain counts will be off that way.  You will now have an object wit ha retain count of 2.  I think.

Comment: @Stefan H No, he shouldn't, since he didn't use `self.FBRP = [[footballResultsParser alloc] init];`

Comment: Good call, i totally missed the fact that he wasn't using the setter for it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also release them in viewDidUnload. For reference, here is the related documentation in the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

> When a low-memory warning occurs, the
>   UIViewController class purges its
>   views if it knows it can reload or
>   recreate them again later. If this
>   happens, it also calls the
>   viewDidUnload method to give your code
>   a chance to relinquish ownership of
>   any objects that are associated with
>   your view hierarchy, including objects
>   loaded with the nib file, ***objects
>   created in your viewDidLoad method***,
>   and objects created lazily at runtime
>   and added to the view hierarchy.
>   Typically, if your view controller
>   contains outlets (properties or raw
>   variables that contain the IBOutlet
>   keyword), you should use the
>   viewDidUnload method to relinquish
>   ownership of those outlets or any
>   other view-related data that you no
>   longer need.

Btw, when releasing, you don't have to check if the object is nil. Sending messages to nil does nothing, it's safe.

Answer (score 2):

Since you set FBRP property to retain, and are taking advantage of synthesize i assume, then just use:

```
self.FBRP = [[[footballResultsParser alloc] init] autorelease];
```

in viewdidload (typically) and release in dealloc.  the retain count should increase by only 1 after the autorelease due to the retain on the property (and yes, use self. notation)

Comment: so the use of self.var is got to do with the use of @property and @synthesize. Hmm always wondered about why its used. I never do. Guess i need to learn more about that.

Comment: you just want to be sure that you're using the accessors that synthesize provides (as it properly handles the retain), in this case setting the FBRP property of this particular view controller

Answer (score 0):

Instead of viewDidLoad method, you should alloc the instance in init method.
And you should init variable _FBRP (or how you call it), but not the property.

```
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {     
        _FBRP = [[footballResultsParser alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and dealloc

```
-(void) dealloc
{
     [FBRP release];
     [super dealloc];
}
```